# Upgrading to 5.45.1 get error

Tags: upgrade, permissions

Upgrading from 5.27.2 to 5.45.1 on Drupal 9.3.2, used [civicrm_drush](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_drush) module, also tried with UI.

Getting following Error:

log file details

```
    [info] Running task: Update legacy prefix id token in greetings (use {contact.prefix_id:label})

    [info] Civi\API\Exception\NotImplementedException: "API (OptionValue, getFields) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)"
    #0 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(437): Civi\API\Request::create("OptionValue", "getFields", (Array:4))
    #1 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractGetAction.php(44): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->entityFields()
    #2 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Generic/DAOGetAction.php(97): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractGetAction->setDefaultWhereClause()
    #3 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Provider/ActionObjectProvider.php(68): Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOGetAction->_run(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\Result))
    #4 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(149): Civi\Api4\Provider\ActionObjectProvider->invoke(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOGetAction))
    #5 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(234): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOGetAction))
    #6 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/MessageTemplates.php(420): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->execute()
    #7 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/Base.php(320): CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_MessageTemplates->replaceTokenInGreetingOptions("contact.prefix_id", "contact.prefix_id:label")
    #8 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Queue/Task.php(74): CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_Base::updateGreetingOptions(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), "contact.prefix_id", "contact.prefix_id:label", "5.43.alpha1")
    #9 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Queue/Runner.php(201): CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))
    #10 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Queue/Runner.php(155): CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext()
    #11 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Upgrade/Headless.php(49): CRM_Queue_Runner->runAll()
    #12 PATH/distro9.test/web/modules/contrib/civicrm_drush/src/Commands/CivicrmDrushCommands.php(435): CRM_Upgrade_Headless->run()
    #13 [internal function](): Drupal\civicrm_drush\Commands\CivicrmDrushCommands->drushCivicrmUpgradeDb((Array:20))
    #14 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(257): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
    #15 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(212): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->runCommandCallback((Array:2), Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
    #16 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(176): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->validateRunAndAlter((Array:3), (Array:2), Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
    #17 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php(350): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->process(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), (Array:3), (Array:2), Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
    #18 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->execute(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #19 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1027): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #20 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand), Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #21 PATH/distro9.test/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

same issue with dashboard, look like its related `getFields` action.

---

i thought, lets try upto `5.41.2`, Upgrade went smooth using drush.

While loading civicrm, i am getting `Authorization failed` error. (mostly on dashboard, api4 with permission check).

```
    $Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
      "message" => "Authorization failed"
      "code" => null
      "exception" => Civi\API\Exception\UnauthorizedException {#3157
        -extraParams: array:1 [
          "error_code" => "unauthorized"
        ]
        #message: "Authorization failed"
        #code: 0
        #file: "PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php"
        #line: 223
        trace: {
          PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php:223 { …}
          PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php:147 { …}
          PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php:234 { …}
          PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/api/api.php:85 { …}
          PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/BAO/Dashboard.php:69 { …}
          PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Contact/Page/DashBoard.php:52 { …}
          PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:313 { …}
          PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
          PATH/distro9.test/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
          PATH/distro9.test/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Civicrm.php:88 {
            Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm->invoke($args)
            › ob_start();
            › $content = \CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke($args);
            › $output = ob_get_clean();
            arguments: {
              $args: array:1 [ …1]
            }
          }
```

e.g.  Membership Tab

```
$membershipTypes = \Civi\Api4\MembershipType::get(TRUE)
      ->execute()
      ->indexBy('id')
      ->column('name');
```

Logged in user have 'administrator` role, and all permission of civicrm are checked.

Also how does `https://distro9.test/civicrm/placeholder-url-path?civicrm-placeholder-url-query=1` url get resolved ? i did not see any class mapping.

Comment: For the very last part, the placeholder-url gets replaced in js/crm.ajax.js. For the first error, that's really strange because EVERY api4 entity has to have a getFields function. Api4 used to be a separate extension - does that site have the old extension installed? In any case it would be better if upgrade steps (i.e. replaceTokenInGreetingOptions()) [didn't use api calls](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/upgrade/#tips-prefer-simple-sql-semantics-over-apibaodao) to avoid this type of thing. That should be improved in that core function I think.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this error today, too. What happened?

1. Upgrade Drupal & CiviCRM to newest version
2. Deleted everything in /sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/
3. Cleared Drupal cache
4. But forgot to visit https://yourdomain.tld/civicrm/upgrade.php after all
   these steps.

Please do a database upgrade (/civicrm/upgrade.php) after you installed new code. I hope this will help you and everybody else with this error message after an upgrade.